# SIMD optimize small matrix multiply (16 x 16) x (16 x 1)

Tags: matrix-multiplication, simd, avx, avx512

What is the best way to carry out the multiplication of a (16 x 16) floating point matrix `M` with a (16 x 1) vector `V` in AVX-512? The approach I can think of is to do an elementwise multiply on each row of the matrix against `V` using `_mm512_fmadd_ps` and then do a horizontal sum on each of the resultant vectors with `_mm512_reduce_add_ps`. For a total of 16 `fmadd` calls and 16 `reduce_add` calls.

My understanding is that the horizontal add step is fairly slow, however. Do we expect this approach to be much faster than a naive non-vectorized C++ implementation? Is there a better way to leverage SIMD than this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally you can have your input data laid out so you can just do 16x FMAs with a broadcast memory source (from each element of the vector), i.e. matrix already transposed.  Then the result will be a vector of the row x column dot-products between your 16x16 and 16x1 inputs.

(Actually 1 vmulps and 15x FMA.  Or probably better, expose some instruction-level parallelism by starting with 2 or 4 plain multiplies, and only combine those FMA dependency chains at the end.  That will take extra a `vaddps` for each extra vector accumulator, but will shorten the critical path latency, and take a lot of burden off of out-of-order execution by not having a 16 * 4 cycle latency dependency chain for it to try to hide.)

With just AVX, not AVX512, broadcast loads can't be used as a memory source operand *for* an FMA instruction, but still cost just 1  single-uop instruction (`vbroadcastss ymm, [mem]`).  But actually that's irrelevant if both operands are coming from memory anyway; the compiler can just choose to do the broadcast load separately and use the full row vector as a memory source operand.

---

Otherwise you don't want to *separately* `_mm512_reduce_add_ps` each vector; instead transpose-and-add pairs of vectors with 2x `_mm512_hadd_ps` (with 2 different vectors each time) and then some manual shuffle and add until you reduce 16x `__m512` to one `__m512` with each element being the horizontal sum of one of the original 16 vectors.

In the 2nd case, I think you just want straight `_mm512_mul_ps` between your vector and a row of the matrix; there's nothing to add to.

`_mm512_reduce_add_ps` isn't a single machine instruction; it will normally compile to 4x shuffle + 4x `vaddps`.
By comparison, 2 shuffles to feed each add to reduce as we shuffle should combine 16 vectors down to 1 in 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15 total adds (and 30 total shuffles), instead of `16 * (4,4)`

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the reply. Could you elaborate on the 1st case?  I'm having trouble visualizing what you mean by broadcast memory source, and where the transpose comes into play.

Comment: Also, for case 2: if I am understanding correctly, this approach would require 15 (8+4+2+1) calls to `_mm512_add_ps`, which is almost the same as the number of `reduce_add` calls in the naive approach. Is this right?

Comment: @rampatowl: yes, but one 1 add (and 2 shuffles) is much cheaper than a chain of 4x shuffle + 4x add (`reduce_add` isn't a real intrinsic, just a function that uses shuffles and adds).  And also it produces the result in one vector, instead of 16 separate scalars that you'd have to store separately.

Comment: Regarding broadcast memory source: AVX and later provides a [broadcast load](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vbroadcast) that loads a single element from memory and broadcasts it to all elements of a register. This has about the same cost as loading a single scalar (cf https://uops.info/html-instr/VBROADCASTSS_ZMM_M32.html).

Comment: Instead of 16 FMAs (actually one mul+15*FMA), one can split the product into halves (having 2*mul+6*fma+1add) to reduce the effect of the 4 cycle FMA latency (if that is a concern ...) -- throughput would be limited by the 16 load operations, anyway.